# How to prevent the data from ckeditor to break the html of the page?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

SO I am using ckeditor for making a blog website. I have stroing the data from ckeditor form in mongo and retrieving it in a different page (in a bootstrap modal). Here's a brief code:

```
                  <CKEditor activeClass="editor" content=
                  {this.state.content}
                   onChange={this.updateContent.bind(this)} />
```

The problem is when I am retrieving this data in a bootstrap modal, the image, paragraphs, and headers - everything floats out of the container. (especially in phone)

Below is my code for displaying the content:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./css/Article.css";
import Comments from "./Comments";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import CKEditor from "ckeditor4-react";


class Article extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      article: "",
      content: "",
    };

  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ content: this.props.data.content });
  }

  createMarkup(){ return {__html: this.props.data.content}; }


  render() {
    const commentId = this.props.id;
    console.log("stae conent " + this.state.content)
    console.log("Article id " + commentId);
    return (
      <div className="article">
        <Modal
          {...this.props}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
          className = "modal-main"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            <h3>  {this.props.data.title} </h3>
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4> {this.props.data.subTitle} </h4>
            <div id = "main">
              <div id = "content"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {this.createMarkup()}/>
              {/* <hr /> */}
              <Comments
                key={Comments.id}
                postId={commentId}
                commentId={commentId}
              />
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now when I try styling these in css

```
#main #container h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#07c;
  }
```

No effect is taking place. I read the documentation and I am still pretty confused.

Answer (score 0):

try to show data inside a div inside the component (comment your modal while trying this
). check if everything fine. if HTML rendered correctly inside div that means some problem with CSS of modal not HTML saved by CKEditor

write down your code as below

```html
<div className="article">

{this.props && this.props.data && this.props.data.content}

<Modal......./>
</div>
```

Comment: I console.log the data  `console.log("Data on content " + this.state.data);` which I am passing in my model. It is shown as an object. `Data on content [object Object]`